# Tools to read consumer offset from kafka 0.9

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using `Kafka 0.9` consumer APIs. I need to check the current offset of consumers for a given consumer group and topic and haven't found any command line tool that would list this information. I tried the following command

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group <group_name>
```

but this doesn't list the consumers, even when I have consumers running/polling.

Based on [Kafka 0.9 new consumer api --- how to just watch consumer offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35333935/kafka-0-9-new-consumer-api-how-to-just-watch-consumer-offsets) seems there is command-line tool for this but I don't know if this is for `Kafka 0.9` consumers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was able to use bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic name> --group <group_name> but seems this is deprecated and will be dropped in releases following 0.9.0.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --describe --group ta-services --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

and gives something like this as a result:

```
GROUP, TOPIC, PARTITION, CURRENT OFFSET, LOG END OFFSET, LAG, OWNER
ta-services, modsec_logs, 0, 2, 2, 0, instance1-0_/127.0.0.1
ta-services, modsec_logs, 1, 9, 9, 0, instance1-0_/127.0.0.1
ta-services, modsec_logs, 2, 1, 1, 0, instance1-1_/127.0.0.1
ta-services, modsec_logs, 3, 1, 1, 0, instance1-1_/127.0.0.1
```

Keep in mind, that this command seems to work *only* when your consumer is up and alive. As soon as you stop it - you won't get any output from the command. I think this is one of the deficiencies of this offset checker in 0.9.x vs 0.8.x. I could not find a way to check offsets of "dead" consumers in 0.9 yet (via scripts, without manually reading data from the _offsets... topics)  - if anybody know how to do that, please post!